How do you serve a generated file using Django?
For example, the Django sitemap middleware, generates a sitemap and then serves it from localhost:8000/sitemap.xml. If I were to serve a file in a similar manner, following the same url structure, how would I do this?
I have a view and urls file:
class FileView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponse(open('myfile.xml').read(), content_type='text/xml')

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        '/myfile.xml',
        PageView.as_view()
    )
]

This will fail to render with a 404, and will constantly append a / to the url, so it looks for localhost:8000/myfile.xml/. However, if I change my urlpatterns to use '/myfile', without the file extension, it renders the file correctly. Is there a correct way to serve this using the file exentsion without resorting to dropping it into static files?

Typically you don't serve static files through Django: Django is not optimized for this, you use nginx for that.

What is probably here the problem is the leading slash.

It's not a static file, it's generated on the fly, mych like a sitemap. As far as I know, sitemaps aren't stored in static

What is probably here the problem is the leading slash. Your path should be:
urlpatterns = [path('myfile.xml', PageView.as_view())]
But typically Django is not designed to serve static files. It has not much means with regard to efficient caching, streaming, etc. Typically you use the webserver like Nginx, Apache, etc. to serve these files.
For more information, see the deploy static files section [Django-doc].
